# values of the normalised histogram do not sum upto one

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability, normalization

I'm trying to plot a histogram using the data that ranges from (0 - 0.2). The normalization works fine when the bin limits are not included.

But when the bin limits are included as shown in the code, the sum is not equal to one anymore.

```
x=data1.data(:,2);
h=histogram(x,50,'BinLimits',[0.0234375 0.2], 'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor','green','Normalization', 'probability');
S=sum(h.Values)
```

Is there a way to normalize within the specified bin limits?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior; according to the docs, when using the 'probability' normalization scheme, the "sum of the bar heights is less than or equal to 1."

To solve your problem, you can apply `histogram()` directly to the desired subset of your data:

```
x=data1.data(:,2);
x=x(x>=0.0234375 & x<=0.2);
h=histogram(x,50, 'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor','green','Normalization', 'probability');
S=sum(h.Values)
```

Comment: Yeah. That's what i did. Was just wondering if the function could do it. Thanks btw!!